# Qt adding child widget in resizeEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget `W` deriving from `QFrame` with layout set to an instance of `QVBoxLayout`. I wonder if the following `resizeEvent` implementation is correct or is it going to cause an infinite loop:

```
void W::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    for (/* some condition based on the new size of this widget */) {
        // Infinite loop or not?
        qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout *>(layout())->addWidget(new QWidget());
    }
}
```

So far it worked for me, is this by pure luck?

Comment: It depends on the condition. Can you show it? If you use `event->size()`, it will keep the size of the event. But any widget insertion may cause a new resize event after function will return.

Comment: @vsz Your bounty changes the question too much. The original question is about a possible infinite loop by calling a resize operation in a resizeEvent. The OP never mentioned anything about the relation between painting/drawing and resizing. The current answer is just fine for the original question. I suggest to create a new question for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay. `W` owns a `QLayout` which owns `QWidget`. Adding the `QWidget` to the `QLayout` does not change the size of `W`. You see this all the time. For example, if you place a child widget in a parent and the parent is too small, the child widget will be clipped. Stately differently, the size of the parent does not stretch to accommodate the size of the child. I believe your code would be a typical way to hide or show widgets based on the size of the parent (for example, when the window size changes).

Comment: I would guess the question was asked (just as I did search for it), because the [manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) for `resizeEvent()` says "No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler."  Does it mean that only `QPainter` -style drawing should be avoided, and adding/removing widgets is fine?

Comment: A similar issue would be the re-arrangement of child widgets, for example, with `setRowStretch()` on layouts. They also shouldn't effect the parent's geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Painting and constructing a hierarchy of widgets are two different things. So, adding `QWidget`s is just fine, but using `QPainter` directly in `resizeEvent` not.

**Hierarchy of `QWidget`s**

A hierarchy of `QWidget`s derivatives (`QLineEdit`, `QPushButton`, ...) is a high level specification of how the graphical user interface should look like and may be ordered using `QLayout` items.

**Painting**

Painting (using `QPainter`) is the process of actually drawing something on the screen and is purely done in the virtual function [`QWidget::paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent). Every derivative of `QWidget` should provide an implementation of this empty base function. The default derivatives (`QLineEdit`, ...) provide an implementation of `paintEvent` based on their current state (size of the widget, current text for a `QLineEdit`, ...) and the current `QStyle` object, which is typically automatically set based on your OS, but may be changed programmatically using [`QWidget::setStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qwidget.html#setStyle) or [`QApplication::setStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setStyle). A repaint can be requested using [`QWidget::update`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qwidget.html#update).

**"Should not/need not" vs "may not"**

The sentence "*No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler.*" is meant for people implementing a custom `QWidget` (with a new implementation of `paintEvent`) to make it clear that you should not implement your painting here, but that a `paintEvent` will be automatically triggered.

["Should not/need not"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189974/why-do-they-say-may-not-for-things-which-people-shouldnt-do) is some advice, they do not write "may not". So, if you for some reason (ex. real-time applications) want an immediate screen refreshment, you may invoke a repaint immediately using repaint, resulting in `paintEvent` being called during `resizeEvent`. As long as all the `QPainter` operations on a `QWidget` are inside a `paintEvent` (as required by the [warning in the QPainter documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qpainter.html#details)), everything is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding widgets to the layout, using `addWidget`, within the `resizeEvent` function is not a problem as it does not instantly trigger a drawing.

You can easily verify this by compiling and executing this simple project:

**dialog.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    bool resizing;
};
```

**dialog.cpp:**

```
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent),
      resizing(false)
{
    new QVBoxLayout(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{

}

void Dialog::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    resizing = true;

    if ( event->size().width() == event->size().height() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Adding widget";
        // Infinite loop or not?
        layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton());
    }

    resizing = false;
}

void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if ( resizing )
    {
        qDebug() << "Painting while resizing widget";
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When you run the program, resize the dialog to make it be square (width==height), some buttons are inserted ("Adding widget" is printed to the console), but you'll never see "Painting while resizing widget" message. This is most likely because `addWidget` sets a dirty display flag that is processed later by the framework. It invalidates the display, but does not repaint it right away.

So what you are doing is fine and does not violate the framework requirement ("No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler.").

However, if you are not confident (maybe the painting could be operated right away on different OS, or in future Qt versions....you can't be sure), you can also delay the insertion by emitting a signal connected to a slot using `Qt::QueuedConnection`, this slot would be executed "later" and then do the call to `addWidget`, guaranteeing that it's done outside the `resizeEvent` function.

Comment: In my opinion, your solution with a `Qt::QueuedConnection` is a misinterpretation of the documentation. The sentence is meant for people implementing a custom QWidget (with a new implementation of `paintEvent`) to make it clear that you should not implement your painting here, but that a `paintEvent` will be automatically triggered.

Comment: ["Should not/need not"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189974/why-do-they-say-may-not-for-things-which-people-shouldnt-do) is some advice, they do not write "may not". So, if you for some reason (ex. real-time applications) want a immediate screen refreshment, you may invoke a repaint immediately using `repaint`, resulting in `paintEvent` being called during `resizeEvent`.

Comment: Using `Qt::QueuedConnection` is not a "solution", it's just a proposed way to make sure you don't do any funny stuff within `resizeEvent` scope.

Comment: The whole point is that it doesn't matter if Qt (or yourself) call [`repaint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qwidget.html#repaint) (triggering an immediate `paintEvent`). As long as all the `QPainter` operations on a `QWidget` are inside a `paintEvent` (as required by [the warning in the `QPainter` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qpainter.html#details)), everything is just fine. So, even your example which tests if `paintEvent` is not called inside a `resizeEvent` is irrelevant to me.

Comment: Can you clarify if I got your point correctly? You are saying that ""No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler." simply means that no `QPainter` should be created within `resizeEvent`, but calling `paintEvent` from here, itself creating a `QPainter` would be OK?

Comment: That is almost what I'm saying. Except for that you may not call `paintEvent` directly, but you should use `repaint` (which is most of the time never needed).

Comment: OK, got your point, but I am not convinced that's what "No drawing need be (or should be) done inside this handler." actually means...I don't understand that it is safe to call `repaint` when I read that, but you may be true, I can't say. The guy who wrote this in Qt doc should be asked ;-)

Comment: This could be the perfect answer if it first answered the original question at least in a short sentence, and only after that would it mention why the "no drawing" rule in the documentation would not cause problems. In its current form, it seems like a comment on the bounty text, I would guess this is why someone voted it down. I'll award the bounty to this answer if this small issue is corrected.

Comment: @vsz (1) I down voted this answer, because I do not agree with the provided answer (to your bounty question) as suggested in my comments. (2) Even with the added first sentence, this is not an answer to the original question. The original question was about the fear of triggering a new `resizeEvent` inside a `resizeEvent`. This is also reflected in the accepted answer: "_Adding the QWidget to the QLayout does not change the size of W._" I really suggest that you create a new question, so we can move the answers and you can accept this answer.